# Is there any where to determine name of table order_product table

Tags: database, laravel, api, eloquent

I'm trying to create and edit order with laravel , but when i call create function i have an error (Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'easyres.order_products) and then if i change table name to order_products i have same error but with (order_product)

Orderproduct model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'count' , 'price'
];
```

Order model :

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('count')->withPivot('price');
}
```

Product model:

```
public function order(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
}
```

function of create:

```
public function createOrder(Request $request)
{

    $order = new Order;
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $order->save();


    $product_ids = $request->products;



    foreach ($product_ids as $index => $productId) {
        $id = $productId['product_id'];
        $count = $productId['count'];
        $product = Product ::find($id);

        $orderProduct = new Orderproduct;
        $orderProduct->product_id = $id;
        $orderProduct->order_id = $order->id;
        $orderProduct->count = $count;
        $orderProduct->price = $product->product_price;
        $orderProduct->save();
    }





    return  response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success'
    ],200);
}
```

function of edit :

```
 public function EditOrder(Request $request , $id){

    $order =  Order::find($id);
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $order->update();

    $product_ids = $request->products;

    $selectedItems = [];

    foreach ( $product_ids  as $key => $productId) {
        $id1 = $productId['product_id'];
        $product = Product ::find($id);
        $count = $productId['count'];


        $selectedItems[$id1] = ['product_id' => $productId['product_id'] , 'count' => $productId['count']  , 'price' => $product->product_price];


       $order->products()->updateExistingPivot($id1, $selectedItems[$id1]);
    }


    return  response()->json([
        'message' => 'Success'
    ],200);


}
```

I want to determine order_product table's name

Comment: Unclear what you're asking

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer. Then, please update your question.

Comment: Also, your table migration would be helpful so post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OrderProduct` model set the table name as a property

```php
protected $table = "order_product";
```

Because Eloquent assumes a plural form as a table name